# Include Linux kernel headers for intellisense in vs code

Tags: linux-kernel, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I want to use VS code for developing linux kernel modules. I added the path to my browse path, but unfortunately it's not working.
Here's my *c_cpp_properties.json*:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${HOME}/Workspaces/kernel-sources/mainline/linux/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${HOME}/Workspaces/kernel-sources/mainline/linux/include/",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 3
}
```

I want to include like `#include <linux/miscdevice.h>`but the intellisense parser is unable to find that file. I changed the parser engine to "Tag Parser" because the new default parser is unable to recursive include files, as they are in the kernel sources.
Any thoughts how to configure my intellisense?

I use vs code 1.19 for ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Franz, it's a bit disappointing that you didn't give any feedback for the answer. There is a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847626/vs-code-does-not-recognize-some-headers-for-c-on-linux) that seems to be a duplicate with your question, but I don't know if your question has been answered, thus I cannot proceed with marking it as a dupe.

Comment: Sorry, but i haven't developed kernel modules since then. I'll have to test seperately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that the `kernel-devel` package is installed.

Where you see green squiggles under a header file `#include`, click on it.
It should generate a `c_cpp_properties.json` file in the `.vscode` directory within your project.

Find the "Linux", "IncludePath" section and add the include paths you need.

Mine ended up looking like this:

```
"name": "Linux",
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}",
    "/usr/include",
    "/usr/local/include",
    "/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64/include/",
    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/include/",
    "/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64/arch/x86/include/"
```

Comment: How to insert `uname -r` to get the correct version without manually changing everything?

Comment: I did not make a research, but I used $HOME/.bashrc to export corresponding environmental variable: export CURRENT_KERNEL_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/include"
Then in .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json I wrote ${env:CURRENT_KERNEL_INCLUDE_PATH}/**
But there are still several include path troubles, which depends on kernel modules build environment: It is definitely necessary to parse kernel Makefiles. I do not know any VSCode extension with such capabilities at present moment.

Answer (score 4):

If anybody is developing linux kernel module, on other machine with Visual Studio Code, for example I write everything on MacOS and test it on VirtualBox with Fedora, then I recommend this configuration:

https://gist.github.com/gyulkkajo/c29c19fc2c64f61d8b6b4892566bf10c

And then copy kernel files to your machine, or for me shared folder. But you only header files, so you can copy whole folders.

Which folders:

- we need `LINUX_PATH/include`, so we copy folder from `{KERNEL_PATH}/include`
- we need `LINUX_PATH/arch/x86/include`, so we copy folder from `{KERNEL_PATH}/arch/x86/include`

Then change all `LINUX_PATH` to path on your local machine with VS Code.

You also need to copy folders: `mm`, `fs` and `kernel` and update your `browse.path` accordingly.